# Select result where two columns are equal and one is different and the concatenation of the different result in a single line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to make a selection from two tables.
It's a table that links the two tables together.
But I would like the third table to have the value that is different for all the tables to concatenate in a row, not to show me each one separately.

table 1 person

```
Id  Name  Last_name  
1    pop       viktor
2    marian   emil
```

table 2  ocupation

```
Id      oc_name
1        driver
2        manager
3        officer
```

table 3 assign_val

```
Id       id_person    id_oc          last_login
1         1               1          12/12/18
2         1               1          13/12/18
3         1               1          14/12/18
```

My code

```
$selet = mysqli_query($con, SELECT * FROM assign_val a INNER JOIN person p ON p.Id = a.id_person INNER JOIN ocupation o ON o.Id = a.id_oc);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){

}
```

This query generates three separate rows so it's not good!
I have to generate only one cross and concatenate the values:

```
12.12.18. "-." 13/12/18. "-". 14/12/18
```

Show it in a single row.
Thank you very much! 
Happy new years!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I quite understand what you want but I'm hoping this is what you want. I inserted the tables you gave and ran this query and it gave me the result below. Just an FYI, the default separator for the `GROUP_CONCAT` method is a comma.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(last_login SEPARATOR '-')
FROM assign_val a INNER JOIN
     person p
     ON p.Id = a.id_person INNER JOIN
     occuptation o
     ON o.Id = a.id_oc
```

Result:

```
2012-12-18-2013-12-18-2014-12-18
```

Comment: The problem is that I have several groups of associations for example: there are more people .... how do I display them?

Comment: So do you mean that you want a concatenated list of dates across the different types of associations?

Comment: @CoderCoder42 . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a further question like getting *multiple* rows with concatenations from the query, then ask *another* question.  I would recommend that you accept this answer, because it appears to be correct.